# EntityManager not injected using @PersistenceContext in JBoss 4.3 (EJB3 and Hibernate 4.3.9 Final)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, entitymanager

I'm trying to create an extended PersistenceContext by having the container inject the EntityManager into a Stateful EJB. With JBoss 4.3.0.GA_06 and Hibernate 4.3.9.Final, the EntityManager is not injected despite annotating the EJB field with @PersistenceContext.

EJB:

```
package com.foo.bar.example;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.LocalBinding;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.SynchronizationType;

@Stateful
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "MyEJB/EntityManagerBean")
public class EntityManagerHolderBean implements EntityManagerHolderLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, synchronization = SynchronizationType.UNSYNCHRONIZED)
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

EJB interface:

```
package com.foo.bar.example;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Local;    
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Local
public interface EntityManagerHolderLocal {    
    EntityManager getEntityManager();
}
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="examplePersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files from this JAR -->
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Deploying the EAR containing the EJB causes JBoss to log the following stacktrace to server.log; I presume that this explains why the injection does not work:

```
2015-05-08 14:46:44,200 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment
2015-05-08 14:46:44,203 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: persistence.units:ear=earmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,unitName=examplePersistenceUnit with dependencies:
2015-05-08 14:46:44,203 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction]     jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding
2015-05-08 14:46:44,205 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.units:ear=earmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,unitName=examplePersistenceUnit
2015-05-08 14:46:44,234 WARN  [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Problem starting service persistence.units:ear=earmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,unitName=examplePersistenceUnit
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceDelegateWrapper.startService(ServiceDelegateWrapper.java:103)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction.install(JmxKernelAbstraction.java:120)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.startPersistenceUnits(Ejb3Deployment.java:628)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.start(Ejb3Deployment.java:352)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Module.startService(Ejb3Module.java:83)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.start(EJB3Deployer.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can JBoss 4.3.0.GA_06 be set up to inject the EntityManager, or is the only alternative to switch to a more recent JBoss version? Further details regarding the EAR structure are in a [Maven-based failing demonstrator project](https://github.com/lauriharpf/jboss-4-3-jpa-ejb) at GitHub.

**Edit**

Attempting to replace the JBoss Hibernate implementation with Hibernate 4.3.9.Final does not seem to work, at least out of the box. If I

1. Remove Hibernate-related JARs (hibernate3.jar, hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar, hibernate-validator.jar) from the server lib directory (e.g. default/lib)
2. Copy the EAR JARs into the sever lib directory
3. Start JBoss

Then deployment still fails, but with a different error:

```
2015-05-19 08:20:47,996 WARN  [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Problem creating service jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.<clinit>(DTDEntityResolver.java:60)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.initializePersistenceUnits(Ejb3Deployment.java:536)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:330)
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Module.createService(Ejb3Module.java:74)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:260)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:243)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.create(ServiceController.java:330)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.create(ServiceController.java:273)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.create(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.create(EJB3Deployer.java:505)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.create(DeployerInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.create(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:180)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:91)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.create(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:959)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This seems to be an incompatibility between the org.jboss.logging.Logger implementation hibernate-core depends on and the org.jboss.logging.Logger class in the shared libs of my JBoss installation; my jboss-eap-4.3.0\jboss-as\lib directory contains a jboss-common.jar, which holds an org.jboss.logging.Logger without a getMessageLogger method.

After the implementation change, contents of my JBoss lib directories are as follows:

```
jboss-eap-4.3.0\jboss-as\lib:

47 469 commons-codec.jar
214 793 commons-httpclient.jar
55 566 commons-logging.jar
256 694 concurrent.jar
<DIR>          endorsed
15 866 getopt.jar
406 583 jboss-common.jar
879 986 jboss-jmx.jar
267 603 jboss-system.jar
376 451 jboss-xml-binding.jar
128 413 log4j-boot.jar
175 202 webdavlib.jar

jboss-eap-4.3.0\jboss-as\lib\server\default\lib:

70 283 activation.jar
445 288 antlr-2.7.7.jar
355 310 antlr.jar
17 260 asm-attrs.jar
26 778 asm.jar
4 951 autonumber-plugin.jar
513 252 bcel.jar
21 300 bindingservice-plugin.jar
167 699 bsf.jar
12 139 bsh-deployer.jar
235 516 bsh.jar
286 184 cglib.jar
47 469 commons-codec.jar
558 375 commons-collections.jar
214 793 commons-httpclient.jar
55 566 commons-logging.jar
313 898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
313 136 dom4j.jar
52 188 ejb3-persistence.jar
28 039 el-api.jar
75 324 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
5 277 940 hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
647 565 hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar
113 371 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
8 748 hsqldb-plugin.jar
705 554 hsqldb.jar
76 551 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
714 195 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
599 322 javassist.jar
226 490 jaxen.jar
725 792 jboss-cache-jdk50.jar
87 170 jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar
20 393 jboss-ejb3x.jar
14 196 jboss-hibernate.jar
423 715 jboss-j2ee.jar
29 390 jboss-jaxrpc.jar
63 836 jboss-jaxws.jar
200 395 jboss-jca.jar
14 227 jboss-jsr77.jar
65 053 jboss-jsr88.jar
57 183 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
11 558 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
152 338 jboss-management.jar
583 242 jboss-messaging-client.jar
1 148 573 jboss-messaging.jar
56 310 jboss-monitoring.jar
8 385 jboss-remoting-int.jar
924 915 jboss-remoting.jar
26 744 jboss-saaj.jar
125 858 jboss-serialization.jar
46 984 jboss-srp.jar
27 717 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
53 284 jboss-transaction.jar
90 744 jboss-vfs.jar
2 139 468 jboss.jar
31 271 jbossjta-integration.jar
552 165 jbossjta.jar
317 324 jbosssx.jar
65 399 jbossts-common.jar
55 112 jbossws-common.jar
69 093 jbossws-framework.jar
77 153 jbossws-jboss42.jar
95 812 jbossws-spi.jar
33 310 jmx-adaptor-plugin.jar
54 286 jnpserver.jar
82 157 joesnmp.jar
81 902 jsp-api.jar
15 151 log4j-snmp-appender.jar
355 760 log4j.jar
5 475 mail-plugin.jar
415 743 mail.jar
2 714 016 ojdbc6.jar
8 827 properties-plugin.jar
397 928 quartz-all.jar
3 546 scheduler-plugin-example.jar
46 045 scheduler-plugin.jar
88 151 servlet-api.jar
109 318 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
2 666 xmlentitymgr.jar
```

Comment: Probably multiple javax.persistence jars in the classpath which are conflicting.

Comment: @mh-dev, that is true. There is an ejb3-persistence.jar in the lib directory of the server. That JAR contains javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider. However, removing ejb3-persistence.jar from the lib directory just causes a different exception, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitTransactionType.

Since JBoss 4.3 uses an old Hibernate, I'm using jboss-app.xml to tell JBoss to favor the EAR JARs (see the Github project). For some reason, the classloading is not working as I would expect it to.

Comment: You can replace the implementation.

Comment: @mh-dev, if you can provide instructions on how to do that (and it resolves the problem), please write an answer and I'll be happy to accept it. Just removing ejb3-persistence.jar from the lib directory and dropping in the new Hibernate jars does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Please try the following. In the lib folder are probably these three dependencies: hibernate3.jar, hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar.
Replace these with your current version and test if it works. It might be necessary to add additional dependencies of hibernate. If it works tell me than I make an anwer for the rest of the world.

Comment: @mh-dev: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it (see the updated answer), but unfortunately without success. Since the JBoss version is old, I'm considering spending time on upgrading it instead of researching this further. In any case, your efforts are appreciated!